# running multiple php script on the single php script

Tags: php, mysql, include, batch-processing

I need to pull 100+ excels and transform to mysql. 
Each excel has different format.So i have created 100 different php files to import each excels like below

```
format1.php
format2.php
format3.php
```

and so on

Now i need to run each script in a batch(not necessarily in a parallel) . Like after completing format1.php  i need to run format2.php  and process runs till the end of the script .. I tried like below

**main.php**

```
include("format1.php");
include("format2.php");
include("format3.php");
```

doing so i faced the **problem of maximum execution time**. I dont have access to  php.ini so i cannot alter maximum execution time. Neither **ini_alter** or **ini_set** is working .

What is the way out

Comment: Why are you running this from the browser instead of the cli?

Comment: i am using shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

if you can use the function: 
`set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: I'm going to bet that if you can't use a php.ini and you can't alter ini settings, that the set_time_limit function is also disabled. this is likely a shared hosting environment and they don't want the cpu to get pinned.